# Rails association with itself not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many

I keep getting this error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#create Couldn't
>   find Relationship with 'id'=[4]

My Schema:

```
  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.boolean "display_in_navbar", default: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My Categories form

```
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.association :active_relationships, collection: Category.order(:name), prompt: "Choose a Category" %>
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

    has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                    inverse_of: :follower,
                                    dependent: :destroy
    has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                    inverse_of: :followed,
                                    dependent: :destroy
    has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
    has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

end
```

Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "Category"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "Category"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

Categories controller:

```
class CategoriesController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description, :display_in_navbar, post_ids: [], active_relationship_ids: [])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding value method and label method explicitly to collection input

`<%= f.association :active_relationships, collection: Category.order(:name).all.map{|cat| [cat.name, cat.id]}, label_method: :first, value_method: :last, prompt: "Choose a Category" 
%>`